# Как реализовать треугольники у блока, чтобы поведение было как на картинке (box-shadow, border)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как реализовать треугольники у блока, чтобы поведение было как на картинке (box-shadow, border)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Вариант на CSS

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  filter:
    drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #888);
}

.card:hover {
  filter:
    drop-shadow(0 0 .5px red)
    drop-shadow(0 0 .5px red)
    drop-shadow(0 0 .5px red)
    drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #888);
}

.card .clip {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 175px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,
    0% 45%,   /* A1 ->  A1       */
    5% 50%,   /* B1 ->     ▷ B1  */
    0% 55%,   /* C1 ->  C1       */
    0% 100%, 100% 100%,
    100% 55%, /* C2 ->       A2  */
    95% 50%,  /* B2 ->  B2 ◁    */
    100% 45%, /* A1 ->       C2  */
    100% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="clip">
    Текст, бокал, все дела
  </div>
</div>
```

Но лучше SVG

Comment: Вижу, что стали активно использовать drop-shadow. Если тени не хватает насыщенности, то просто продублируйте её там же с теми же параметрами (я про красную обводку). И в исходном состоянии (без hover), лучше всё-таки тени дать или прозрачность или чёрный - проглядывает немного.

Answer (score 3):

А как вам такой вариант?

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 45%, 96% 50%, 100% 55%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 55%, 4% 50%, 0 45%);
}

.card:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 45%, 96% 50%, 100% 55%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 55%, 4% 50%, 0 45%);
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

Или с "тенью":

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.2);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 46%, 97% 50%, 100% 54%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 54%, 3% 50%, 0 46%);
}

.card:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 45%, 96% 50%, 100% 55%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 55%, 4% 50%, 0 45%);
}

.card:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 45%, 96% 50%, 100% 55%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 55%, 4% 50%, 0 45%);
}

.card:hover:before {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

Добавим немного легкой анимации:

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.2);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 46%, 97% 50%, 100% 54%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 54%, 3% 50%, 0 46%);
}

.card:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 45%, 96% 50%, 100% 55%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 55%, 4% 50%, 0 45%);
}

.card:hover:before {
  left: 2px;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  animation: card 1s linear;
}

@keyframes card {
  0% {
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  99.9% {
    left: 2px;
    width: calc(100% - 4px);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 45%, 96% 50%, 100% 55%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 55%, 4% 50%, 0 45%);
  }
}

.card:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 45%, 96% 50%, 100% 55%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 55%, 4% 50%, 0 45%);
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```